# Comando não está funcionando

Tags: java

[image]

Eu tenho um código para remover um índice que foi digitado pelo usuário, só que ele não está funcionado corretamente, ele apaga dois valores quando era pra apagar um único, ou então apaga um posição que não foi a correta

```
public double remove(int K) {
    double remover = 0;
    if(!(K>=0 && K <size())) {
        System.out.println("Posição invalida!");
    }

    for(int k=K;k< size()-1;k++) {
        remover =vet[K]= 0;
    }
        
    return remover;
}
```

Comment: A lógica do loop de remoção está errada, a variável "remover" é inútil e o núcleo devia ser algo como "vet[k] = vet[k+1]", tipo uma dança das cadeiras, é só pensar um pouco.

Comment: Desculpe a pergunta mas, poderia de me explicar melhor? é minha primeira vez na programação e estou tendo algumas dificuldades

Comment: Vou colocar na resposta mesmo

Answer (score 1):

O bloco que elimina o item deveria ser algo como:

```
remover = vet[K];
for(int k = K; k < size() - 1; k++) {
    vet[k] = vet[k+1];
}
```

A ideia é fazer uma "dança das cadeiras", eliminando o item K copiando o item da posição K+1 para cima dele, e depois fazer o mesmo para todas as posições adiante.
Se o vetor era

```
a b c d e f
```

e deseja remover a posição 2 (supondo que vet[0] igual a "a"), o loop acima movimenta o array assim a cada ciclo:

```
a b c d e f   (antes)
a b d d e f   (k = 2)
a b d e e f   (k = 3)
a b d e f f   (k = 4)
```

Feito isso, para descartar o elemento final, o tamanho do vetor pode ser diminuído de 1. Não está claro como fazer isso no seu programa porque a pergunta não mostra a implementação da função size(), então não dá pra saber se o tamanho está armazenado numa variável, etc.

O que seu bloco original fazia era apenas atribuir 0 ao elemento da posição a ser eliminada, sem mover os demais de lugar.